# Firebase Realtime Database not working on Android 12 Api 31 While It's working fine on lower versions. A vpn connection is needed on Android 12

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-12

**Realtime Database** not working on **Api 31** without **VPN Connection**
. A VPN connection is needed on **Android 12**

It works fine on other Android versions.

I also tried the app on Physical Devices instead of Emulators but that didn't worked

[Screenshot Without VPN connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0S32.png)

[Screenshot With VPN Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WkZW.png)

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Load">

    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Hello World!"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Test/Test 2");
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Read from the database
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                        // whenever data at this location is updated.
                        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        textView.setText(value);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.admin.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FirebaseTest"

        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Where is your code. Your question tell nothing to me

Comment: @androidXP You can see code Now!!